# Get "Unable to delete directory" error when trying to delete all the sub-directories with ant

Tags: ant, delete-file, subdirectory

My goal is to perform a full clean-up of my workspace.

I try to delete all files and sub-directories with ant, including .svn dirs.

```
    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" defaultexcludes="false">
            <include name="**"/>
        </fileset>
    </delete>
```

It does remove all the sub-directories. But, unfortunately, I get the following error (on windows):

> "Unable to delete directory {working dir}"

How to avoid this error?

For information, `fileset` documentation specifies that `**` matches zero or multiple directories. Tried several things to exclude current directories but did not find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When adding

don't get the error anymore...

This is may be due to the fact that the delete task is trying to delete the script being executed !

Comment: can you be more specific please... you answered `when adding don't get the error anymore` `when adding` what ?